# npm informixdb driver odbc dont show special characters

Tags: node.js, odbc, informix

I have a problem with informixdb driver (https://www.npmjs.com/package/informixdb)

I can make selects/update to a informix server without problems, but the special characters (accents) are no showing and � instead.

```
var informix = require('informixdb')

async function executeQuery(sentence){
  var option = { codeSet: 'ISO-8859-1'};
  connStr = "SERVER="+process.env.SERVER+";DATABASE="+process.env.DB+
    ";HOST="+process.env.HOST+
    ";SERVICE="+process.env.PORTDB+";"+"UID=--;PWD=--";
  var connection = null;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =\> {
    connection= informix.open(connStr, option);
    connection.query(sentence, function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
          reject(err)
       }else{
         resolve(data);
       }
    })
  }).catch(e => {
     console.log(e);
     throw new Error(manejoErrorEnCatch(e,'Error al ejecutar ' ));
  }).finally(function() {
   connection.close();
  });
}
```

The result:
{
"idmeta": "1 ",
"descripcion": "EVALUACI�N DE OTs",
}

I use the var option to send the codeSet, try with ISO-8859-1, UTF8, windows-1252 but anyone works. I can write anything in codeSet and the result is the same.

Comment: If should work if you include DB_LOCALE and CLIENT_LOCALE in the connection string, something like "DB_LOCALE=es_es.UTF8" and "CLIENT_LOCALE=es_es.CP1252".